# PostGIS ST_OffsetCurve fails for some lines

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Using PostgreSQL and PostGIS I get an error when using ST_OffsetCurve for some specific line geometries:
"lwgeom_offsetcurve: noded geometry cannot be offset"

Example:

`SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(288249.918098328 5615135.51135102,288293.425429089 5615086.62800628,288231.885629119 5615155.77174104,288249.918098328 5615135.51135102)'), -5.6875)`

This is a closed line and the last three points are on a straight line.
PostGIS version is 3.0 on Windows.

Changing any coordinates or even just the offset value slightly removes this error.
Is it possible to prevent the error without changing numeric values?

Comment: what is the srid of your geometry? welcome to SO!

Comment: The issue seems to be independent from srid used (several tried out). I left srid out for simplicity.

Comment: e.g. srid 32632

Answer (score 1):

Update to PostGIS version 3.1 solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for reporting +1 Could you find out if it was a bug in 3.0? I cannot find it in the release notes: https://postgis.net/docs/release_notes.html#idm41899

Answer (score 0):

maybe ST_MakeValid fix this problem
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeValid.html

And it is also better to pass srid as second parametr in ST_GeomFromText

```
SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(ST_MakeValid(ST_GeomFromText(...., your srid)), -5.6875)
```

Comment: The example geometry is a valid one (ST_IsValid gives true). So unfortunately ST_MakeValid has no effect here.